# Xamarin.Forms: Bind SwipeView to code and get events

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am quite new to xamarin.forms.

So I set up a swipeview (https://github.com/markolazic88/SwipeCardView/blob/master/docs/index.md)

But I can't seem to understand what they mean by "glueing" xaml with C#' together.

In the docs it says there are eventhandlers like this one:

```
void OnSwiped(object sender, SwipedCardEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Direction)
    {
        case SwipeCardDirection.None:
            break;
        case SwipeCardDirection.Right:
            break;
        case SwipeCardDirection.Left:
            break;
        case SwipeCardDirection.Up:
            break;
        case SwipeCardDirection.Down:
            break;
    }
}
```

But just adding this function into the connect class doesn't work. Nothing fires. I was however able to access the swipeview like this:

```
public Screen_SwipeView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<string> data = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
    swipeview_swipeview.ItemsSource = data;
}
```

But this method isn't mentions in the docs.

How can I get the eventhandlers to fire. I feel like I am missing the bridge between the xaml component and the code.

I also tried making a class and letting it inherit from this components but that only threw errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also define the SwipeView properties (LeftItems, RightItems, TopItems, BottomItems) in your Xaml and then bind their command properties to a Command object define in your viewmodel. Example :

```
 <SwipeView>
    <SwipeView.RightItems>
        <SwipeItems>
            <SwipeItem Text="Annuler" 
               IconImageSource="deleteitem.png" 
               BackgroundColor="LightPink"
               Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference yourViewName}, Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand}"
               CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
        </SwipeItems>
    </SwipeView.RightItems>
</SwipeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy one:

```
        swipeview_swipeview.Dragging += OnDragging;
        swipeview_swipeview.Swiped += OnSwiped;
```